# Can't display javascript function's return value on react UI

Tags: reactjs

I have the below code in react,this is all working fine in displaying the result on console.
But, i wanted this to get displayed on UI through react.

```js
class NewRandomGenerator extends Component {
  numbers = props => {
    const set = new Set();
    let maxNumber = 50;
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; ) {
      let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxNumber + 1);
      if (!set.has(randomNumber)) {
        set.add(randomNumber);
        i++;
      }
    }
    console.log(set);
    return set;
  };

  render() {
    const set1 = this.numbers();
    return (
      <div>Set Values {set1.forEach(element => console.log(element))}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`forEach` doesn't return anything and you can't iterate over a `Set`.

You can just make it an array and React will render it

```js
<div>
  Set Values {[...set1]}
</div>
```

Or make it an array before

```js
render() {
  const set1 = [...this.numbers()];

  return (
    <div>Set Values {set1}</div>
  );
}
```

If you need to iterate over an array use `.map` and don't forget the `key`

```js
render() {
  const set1 = [...this.numbers()];

  return (
    <div>
      Set Values
      {set1.map(element => (
        <span key={element}>{element}</span>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just spread your set in the div.

```
 <div>
  Set Values {[...set1]}
 </div>
```

Or you can just use map

Comment: I wanted to further split the elements in an set, but these Set elements were printing all together in UI.
I have used arrays and got the expected output.

numbers = (props) => {
        let arr =[]
        var maxNumber = 50;
            for(let i =0; i<5; ){
                var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * maxNumber) + 1)
                if(!arr.includes(randomNumber)){
                    arr.push(randomNumber)
                    i++
                   }
                }
      console.log(arr)
            return arr
        }